# saving data to txt file using python

Tags: python

I am new in python, and I really need some help. I am doing this memory game where I need to save user, game score and time into a text file using python. I have tried several ways to do it, but nothing seems to work. I need to get the text what is shown after game on  html page (statsParagraph) into *txt file using python
In my html code I have this:

```
<form  action="http://....python file addres" method="GET">
<p id="statsParagraph" name="user" value=""></p>
</form>
```

in my javascript code I have this:

```
function showstatistic(){ 
var user = prompt ("What is your name?","");
alert (user + ". game is over!")
var s="";
for(var i=0;i<statistic.length;i++){
    var t=statistic[i].time;
    var timeString= (t-(t%60))/60+":"+(t%60);
    s += "User: " + user 
    +" <br/>"
    + " Game #"+ (i+1) +"  "
    +" <br/>"
    +" Guessed: "+ statistic[i].guessed
    +" <br/>"
    +" Minus points: "+ statistic[i].minuses
    +" <br/>"
    +" Guessed right: "+ statistic[i].plusPoints
    +" <br/>"
    +" Time: "+ timeString
    +" <br/>"
    +" <br/>";
    }   
$("#statsParagraph").html(s);
}
```

Comment: use ajax to send data to your server and thee save it in text file

Answer (score 1):

You would open the code with

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

target = open(filename, 'w')
```

then assign each piece of info to a variable with an appropriate name

```
time = #x
score = #x
user = #name
```

then type the following

```
target.write(time)
target.write("\n")
target.write(score)
target.write("\n")
target.write(user)
target.write("\n")

target.close()
```

when you run the file you would run it with an argument, that argument being the file where you would like to write the info.

```
>python mymemorygame.py savegamefile.txt
```

You may also want to consider truncating the file, before writing to it depending on how you are saving the info (multiple files or one file)

I hope this helps, apologies if it doesn't I may have misunderstood what it is you are looking to do.

alternatively, it may be harder to write but easier to manage/implement, you could put the info in to a list that you store in a single file, rather than writing new .txt files all the time.