# how to store html form data into file

Tags: python

My HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>INFORMATION</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <form action = "/cgi-bin/test.py" method = "post">
        FirstName:
        <input type = "text" name = "firstname" /><br>
        LastName:
        <input type = "text" name = "lastname" /><br>

        <input type = "submit" name = "submit "value = "SUBMIT">
        <input type = "reset" name = "reset" value = "RESET">
        </form>
   </body>
```

My PYTHON CODE (test.py) which is in cgi-bin directory:

```
#!usr/bin/python

form = web.input()
print form.firstname
print form.lastname
```

what should i do to store html data in some file ??

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451400/saving-data-to-txt-file-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it to a file!

```
#!usr/bin/python

import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
with open ('fileToWrite.txt','w') as fileOutput:
    fileOutput.write(form.getValue('firstname'))
    fileOutput.write(form.getValue'(lastname'))
```

Oh, and you need to have write permission into the file. So for example if you are running apache, `sudo chown www-data:www-data fileToWrite.txt` should do it.

Comment: whenever i am saving it shows: "test.py" 
"test.py" E212: Cannot open file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: So you have some other process that has the file open, or you do not have write permissions to that folder or file

Comment: By the way, is this by any chance located at `/var/www` on a Linux box? If so, you need root permissions to write to the file or directory

Comment: i have created an public_html directory, in that dir i have an html file name index.html which is above and i have another folder name cgi-bin in the public_html. in this cgi-bin i have an test.py file which contains the above code

Comment: Join me on chat room titled "Python help for John John"

Comment: i cant chat..it shows u must have 20 reputation. and i m jus a mewbie. lease continue over here

Comment: Okay, so in your public_html/cgi-bin folder, can you create new directories?

Comment: <deleted my gmail id> Looks like you are not around: hope this gets resolved quickly for you

Comment: there is no such module web in python

Comment: Traceback:IO Error: bad file descriptor

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('/path/to/form.txt','w') as out_fh:
    out_fh.write(form.firstname)
    out_fh.write(form.lastname
```

The webserver will need to have write permission to the directory you want to create the file in.

Comment: whenever i am saving it shows: "test.py" "test.py" E212: Cannot open file for writing Press ENTER or type command to continue