# Python HTML writing form data to a file

Tags: python, html, forms, input

Trying to write a simple app that:

1. Presents an html form to get to get input data (a greeting and a name).
2. Displays the data in the browser, and then (here is the part I cannot figure out)
3. Saves the input form data to a simple .txt file

Here is the python code:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/hello', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base='layout')


class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form() # returns form to browser

    def POST(self): # gets name and greeting data back
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
        greeting = "%s ... %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting) #displays index.html
        with open ('projects/forms/ninja.txt)', 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.write(form.getValue("greet"))
        out_file.write(form.getValue("name"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here is the hmtl form:

```
<h1>this is hello_form</h1>

<form action="/hello" method="POST">
    A Greeting: <br>
    <input type="text" name="greet">
    <br/>
    Your Name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br/>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I have searched other answers, including this one:

[how to store html form data into file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562790/how-to-store-html-form-data-into-file)

But I cannot seem to find the information to get this going.

Comment: You can't do anything after the return statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're performing a POST request on `/hello` with this line.

```
<form action="/hello">
```

However, you haven't defined a controller for this route. As a result, nothing happens.

Either make a POST on `/Index` or create a handler for `/hello`

Also, I would highly recommend a framework for this. Something small, like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: Agreed. Some frameworks make simple things more difficult, but Flask is really easy to work with.

Comment: They are already clearly using a framework, web.py, and just as clearly have set the /hello route to point to the Index handler.